# Displaying results in the column based on multiple ID condition

Tags: sql, database, validation, ms-access-2010

This is my query :

```
SELECT Reference.quote_date As Date, Customer.name As Name ,
       Customer.surname AS Surname, Customer.postcode, Customer.telephone,
       Reference.ref_ID AS PolicyRefNo, Reference.agent_ID,
FROM Customer INNER JOIN
     Reference
     ON Customer.customer_ID = Reference.customer_ID;
```

I would like to add additional column that would presents results for Tel or F2F activity

So if the reference.call_id=1,reference.call_id=2 or  reference.call_id=3 then results will be presented in the new column called Tel as 1

IF the reference.call_id=4, reference.call_id=5, reference.call_id=6 then results will be presented in the new column called F2F as 1

I am currently working on Access data base
Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Reference.quote_date As Date, Customer.name As Name ,
       Customer.surname AS Surname, Customer.postcode, Customer.telephone,
       Reference.ref_ID AS PolicyRefNo, Reference.agent_ID,
       (reference.call_id IN(1,2,3))  as Tel,
       (reference.call_id IN(4,5,6)) as F2F
FROM Customer INNER JOIN
     Reference
     ON Customer.customer_ID = Reference.customer_ID;
```

Comment: I just tried to run your query and unfortunately  comes with an error sarong that Syntax error missing in query expression 'CASE WHEN reference.call_id IN(1,2,3) then 1 end'

Comment: it looks like the query works, the only problem i am getting is : results are presented as negative values: for example -1

Comment: @Magda Really? Weird, if so just add *-1 on it -> (reference.call_id IN(1,2,3)) * -1

Comment: this is now resolved issues, Thank you again. Still not sure why results were presented as negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Reference.quote_date As Date, Customer.name As Name , Customer.surname AS Surname , Customer.postcode, Customer.telephone, Reference.ref_ID AS PolicyRefNo, Reference.agent_ID,
CASE WHEN Reference.call_id IN ('1','2','3') THEN '1'
         ELSE '0' END AS Tel
     CASE WHEN Reference.call_id IN ('4','5','6') THEN '1'
         ELSE '0' END AS F2F

FROM Customer INNER JOIN Reference ON Customer.customer_ID = Reference.customer_ID;
```

Comment: I am still getting error message : this time it is saying  that " the Select statement includes a reserved word or argument name that is misspelled or the punctuation is incorrect.  Its Access data base that i am working on ,